# BIOS/UEFI update and BitLocker suspension

Tags: disk-encryption, bitlocker, bios, updates, uefi

I can read on many pages that when you update your BIOS/UEFI, you need to suspend BitLocker (for information, mine is configured to ask for a password at startup, no TPM in my machine).

But none of these pages tell on which devices you have to do this...

- only on the actual internal active system disk ? And what if you have a dual boot ?
- on all the possible system disks that can be run on the machine ?
- on all internal drives (for now I just have one internal system drive connected, but have another internal bitlocked drive not connected into the computer but stored in a cabinet) ?
- on all external drives and flash drives (I guess no as the option does not seem to be there) ?

And on any of these, if you update the BIOS without suspending BitLocker, do you have to type the recovery key forever ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ... you don't have a TPM? So, you're just using the software encryption part of BitLocker?

Comment: If you don't have a TPM, then you don't need to suspend BitLocker because BitLocker is not doing system integrity. Just like the wiki says: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker

Comment: @schroeder:ok, thank you. Yes, I'm using a password only access. And what if I finally use a TPM, or the hardware encryption capability of my hard drive (a Crucial MX500) ?

Comment: @Ramhound:Yes, but refering to my question : on which drives do this have to be done and what are the consequences of not doing it speaking of the recovery key that will be asked ?

Comment: @schroeder:I know this seems to be ASUS specific (I have a MSI motherboard), but are you sure of what you said according to what I can read on this page that seems to be general affirmations : https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1034920/, that says that a needed key used by BitLocker is stored into the firmware of the motherboard and would be erased by a BIOS update ?

Comment: @Ramhound:Thank you. So if I understand you well, using a TPM, I won't be able to have 2 bootable and BitLocked system drives that I could switch. And using a password only access for BitLocker, without a TPM, I will be able to have those 2 system drives. Is this right ?

Comment: @Ramhound:If I have 2 system disk in the machine that I may swap, those 2 BitLocked. Will each activated BitLocker store it's key in the TPM, Or is the key stored into the TPM shared by all the BitLocked system drives ? If it is shared, I assume I wil have to suspend BitLocker on each system drive.

Comment: @Ramhound:Thank you. So if I use a TPM and want to have 2 BitLocked system disks A and B that I can switch, the BitLocking of B will override the key previously stored in the TPM by the BitLock of A, and I will then have to use the recovery key when booting on A ever and ever. Or have to override the key stored into the TPM with the one used by A and then it will be the same problem for booting on B. Is that correct ?